# Term used to describe a particular sample

Tags: distributions, outliers, sample

Suppose that we know that captured data follow a particular distribution.

We have 10 sample. 9 of them are close to the supposed distribution but the last sample seems to be very distant, or event "abberant".

What is the term to use to qualify this sample ? Maybe "outlier sample" ?

Thank you

Comment: The two-word phrase "outlier sample" is highly unusual--I'm sure I have never seen this. (I can imagine several different ways in which someone unfamiliar with statistical terminology might come up with such a phrase.) Could you provide the context in which you read or heard this?  In the meantime, please search our site for [outlier](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=outlier) and read some of the relevant posts.

Comment: In the context of a sample which is very distant from a supposed probability distribution. For instance we generate a sample from a Poisson distribution and we obtain something which is close to a Gauss distribution. I'm looking for the correct term.

Comment: Do you mean 'outlier'? Please note that a *sample* in statistics [has a specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_%28statistics%29). It doesn't mean a single data value.

Comment: "Please note that a sample in statistics has a specific meaning. It doesn't mean a single data value." Yes I know that. Outlier(s) refers to a single value (or quite limited number of values), but I'm looking for the correct term to use when the problem relates to the entire sample, not a single value...

Comment: What I find on Google does not conform with your description in the comments. The first hit at http://www.molmine.com/magma/global_analysis/outlier_detection.html, for instance, uses "sample" in the sense of a *single* (multivariate) case from a batch of related data, not in the statistical sense to which @Glen_b refers.  Please edit your question to clarify your meaning.

Comment: Does the phrase in your question originate from somewhere? The "sample is from a different distribution to the one supposed" situation described in your comments doesn't necessarily have a short descriptive term; at least I'm not sure I'm aware of one, except perhaps in particular circumstances (such as in explicit goodness of fit testing, where you might talk about the sample being from the alternative, for example.)

Comment: +1 Thanks for improving the question. While you might use a term like 'outlier sample' (and I imagine perhaps even be understood), I'd probably say 'discrepant sample'.